# Python Flask how to use Response to serve from a generator from a mongo query

Tags: python, flask

Say that my function "search()" fetches some content in the mongodb and returns the generator.

My flask view function looks like this

```
@app.route("search/")
def search_page():
   generator = search()
   return Response(generator)
```

But if I do that, I get this error:

```
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 180, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 171, in execute
    write(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 151, in write
    assert type(data) is bytes, 'applications must write bytes'
AssertionError: applications must write bytes
```

The generator itself would yield several json values. I could always use the generator to construct a list and return the list, but I would like to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems in your code.

1. You should be sure that your generator yield string type value each time.
2. Need to use stream_with_context method, which can be imported from flask

Here is the example:

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem – the error says it must write bytes, so you need to write bytes as your response.
So in your `search()` function you could do something like:

```
bytes = json.dumps(your_content_from_mongo).decode('utf-8')
```

which will decode your JSON from mongo to bytes.

Comment: I tried it with other library than mongo and it doesn't work, you have maybe other suggestions ? thanks

Comment: I think that should be `decode` to convert unicode to bytes.